# Custom form integrated with Google Forms does not capture data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-forms

I have set up a custom HTML & JavaScript form that integrates with Google Forms to capture data. It doesn't work too well at the moment though, the data does not get sent at times.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

function validateEmail(email) {
        var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(email);
    }

    function postToGoogle() {
                var fname = $('#fname').val();
                var lname = $('#lname').val();
                var email = $('#email').val();
                var mobile = $('#mobile').val();
                var answer = $('#answer').val();

                if ((fname !== "") && (lname !== "") && (email !== "") && (mobile !== "") && ((answer !== "") && (validateEmail(email)))) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "https://docs.google.com/a/forms/d/XXXX/formResponse",
                        data: {"entry.1475885094" : fname, "entry.1313744185" : lname, "entry.710517602" : email, "entry.2041953514" : mobile, "entry.1669156751": answer},
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "xml",
                        statusCode: {
                            0: function() {
                                alert("Thank you for your entry");
                            },
                            200: function() {
                                alert("Thank you for your entry");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
             
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#entryForm').submit(function() {
                    postToGoogle();
                    return false;
                });
            });
});
```

```html
<div id="entryForm" class="contact-us-form">
    <form id="callus" target="_self" onsubmit="" action="">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
            <input id="fname" type="text" name="fname" class="input_field form__input__text">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
                <input id="lname" type="text" name="lname" class="input_field form__input__text">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input id="email" type="text" name="email" class="input_field form__input__text" placeholder="youremail@email.com">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="mobile">Mobile Number:</label>
            <input id="mobile" type="text" name="mobile" class="input_field form__input__text" placeholder="e.g. 0123456789">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="answer">Answer:</label>
            <input id="answer" type="text" name="answer" class="input_field form__input__text" placeholder="e.g. 5">
        </fieldset>
        <div style="width: 100%; display: block; text-align: center;">
            <button id="send" type="submit" class="btn--orange btn--big buy_btn oosButton">
                Submit
            </button>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 100%; display: block; float: right; padding-top: 15px;">
            <div class="requestSubmited" style="display:none; text-align: center;">Your entry has been sent!</div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

There must be something wrong with my JavaScript. Would appreciate any help

Comment: You need to debug your code.  You'll need to start at the beginning, and enter a `console.log('some text: ' + aVariableName);` statement, and see what is being returned for values in your variables.  In some browsers, using the f12 key opens the browser console.  That's where the `console.log()` statements get printed.

Comment: Console doesn't seem to help, it still doesn't work

Comment: You'll need to spend some time on your own learning how to program.